# Передать переменную из одного фрагмента в другой

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть одно активити: "activity_armatura.xml". И в нём два фрагмента: "fragment_armatura_weight.xml" и "fragment_armatura_length.xml".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Находясь на первом фрагменте вводим диаметр и нажимаем на кнопку "Рассчитать" и он высчитывает вес арматуры. При слайде влево т.е. переходе на другой фрагмент диаметр необходимо вводить заново. Вопрос, как передать введеный диаметр из одного фрагмента в другой после нажатия на кнопку "Рассчитать" в первом фрагменте.

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html (в конце по вашему вопросу, но почитать можно и все)

Answer (score 0):

Храни на активности,в фрагменте потом делай getActivity() и получай или изменяй нужное тебе значение

Comment: а как мне хранить на активности если пользователь вводит информацию во фрагменте

Comment: Создай в активности метод getDiameter(). В фрагменте используй (YourMainActivity getActivity()).getDiameter(). Тоже самое можно и для setDiameter(int diameter). Вот ссылка на пример с использованием делегата https://metanit.com/java/android/8.5.php

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать интерфейс.

Фрагмент1 (из него будет передаваться значение переменной в Фрагмент2):

```
private CallBackGetVar callBackGetVar;

public interface CallBackGetVar {
  void onCallBack (int var); //искомая переменная
}
...
callBackGetVar.onCallBack(777); //в нужном месте вызывается функция, куда передается значение переменной
```

Фрагмент2 (должен реализовывать этот интерфейс через implements):

```
 @Override
    public void onCallBack(int var) {
       //ваш код
    }
```